Present infinitive vs perfect infinitive
What would be the difference between the below two sentences?
"I want it to be completed by Sunday"
"I want it to have been completed by Sunday"
What is the difference between the use of the present and the perfect infinitive here? Also, does the choice depend on the 'main' verb?

I don't think there's much difference. If you change "by" to "on" there's a subtle difference.

@Barmar I have learned that present present infinitive does not indicate the time of an event happening whereas perfect infinitive is used to indicate event before another event. Here, perfect infinitive seems more suitable to be as it indicates the work's completion demand before sunday. Whereas the first one just does not seem technically correct to me.

It's perfectly idiomatic, though.

There's no good reason to introduce an auxiliary [to] be at all. Just say "I want it completed by Sunday". But note that most native Anglophones would say "I want it done by Sunday" anyway.

"I want it to have been completed by Sunday" might be more natural if you don't know whether it has already been completed. But I think that's splitting hairs and nobody would rely on there being a distinction. And you'd probably say the shorter thing instead. Or ask if it was already completed.

There is not much difference in the two sentences, practically speaking.
However, different tenses can affect when the sentences can be used. This is somewhat subtle, but to explore all the tense possibilities, here goes:
I want it to be completed by Sunday.
That sentence, using present tense (want) and past participle (completed) can be said only before Sunday.
In contrast, the "have been completed" phrasing adds a past reference to a present statement:
I want it to have been completed by Sunday.
That could be said before or after Sunday. As an example: "What? It isn't completed? I want it to have been completed by Sunday." (before now, in other words)
However, if you are speaking about the past, to be completely clear, the past perfect "had wanted" is precise:
"I had wanted it to be completed by Sunday."
That is someone saying that both the "wanting" and the expected "completion" are in the past.

You can also use the simple past: "I wanted it to have been completed by Sunday." I think this is what most Americans would say.

Or just "I wanted it completed by Sunday."

Agreed, the simplest phrasing is probably "I want it completed by Sunday" and (after Sunday) "I wanted it completed by Sunday".

The second formulation invites us to think (although it does not logically imply) that there is some further activity for which the completion of the work is a prerequisite. One thus may naturally say:

I plan to work on the project on Sunday, so I want your part of it to have been completed by Sunday.

On the other hand, if I don't have any intention of looking at your work any time soon, and I am imposing the Sunday deadline for some other reason (e.g. to see how fast you can work), it would be more natural to say:

I want it to be completed by Sunday.

The difference is, however, subtle, and for most ends and purposes the two formulations are interchangeable.
